# I'm getting android:exported error in merged Manifest

Tags: android, manifest, merged-manifest

This my problem: I'm getting error in my manifest file but I think I'm set all `android:exported` properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmCxO.png)

Merging Errors: Error: Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. SpaceWeb.app main manifest (this file)

#### This my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.teamwincc.web">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="com.teamwincc.web.Utilities.MainLanguageApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/your_app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        tools:targetApi="n">
        <activity
            android:name="com.teamwincc.web.Activity.NoInternetConnectionActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.teamwincc.web.Activity.AppIntroActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.teamwincc.web.Activity.Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.teamwincc.web.Activity.WebViewActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="https://www.google.com/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/AdMob_app_ID" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: add android:exported="false" to first 2 activities and to understand why read from the link you posted

Comment: sir i'm already do it set android:exported="false" to first 2 activities but nothing worked